# Get image code from url, Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I'm creating image uploader for my website. I figured out how to upload image from computer and wrote the whole processing script; Now I need to add an option to upload an image from web. My script works fine after the image is converted into 64 bit format:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAMCAgIC
```

Looks like it is impossible to do anything helpful with image before it is on my server, so I have this script which creates a temporary copy of the image on my host:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://cs6045.vk.me/v6045344/43ce/D7BD4GsCmG4.jpg");
file_put_contents("image.png",$content);
```

So, what I need to do is to take a link "image.png" in JavaScript and transform it to 64 bit format to apply further actions in JavaScript. I can't find a solution anywhere, can someone help?

Comment: you mean base64 ? right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [take a look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript), where a complete solution to convert an image to base64 is provided. This requires HTML5 tho, so your client needs a relatively up-to-date browser.

There seems tho to be some issues between the browsers, since they process image data differentely. If you want 100% the same Base64 encoding as your PHP-script, I suggest you simply make an AJAX-call to the script, which processes the image. Then it returns the Base64 string.

Comment: im not quite understanding this code, is img a string like "image.png"? If so, I cant make it work

Comment: oh, sure it is a new Image element